# Date.parse about FormatException

Tags: dart, flutter

the time is "Mon Jan 21 06:46:09 +0000 2019".When I use DateTime.parse(),It's will show FormatException.How can I do to format the time.

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Comment: Set DateFormat properly. it wont get any FormatException

Comment: `DateTime.parse` doesn't support random formats. You need to create your own parsing function that splits the string into date and time parts and creates a new `DateTime` instance.